# DataTables PDF Export ignoring HTML Entity Encoding

Tags: datatables, laravel-backpack

We are using Laravel Backpack v5 with the $this->crud->enableExportButtons(); function.

If we have a special character like '&' in our records, and we export to PDF, then it becomes '&' instead. If we do it in

[image: example of pdf file with wrong entity encoding]

How can we solve this?

I already tried to add ->escape(true) to the fields in question, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to disable escapes for that column by setting the `escaped` attribute to `false`.

```php
CRUD::column('name')->escaped(false);
```

More info: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-columns#escape-column-output-1